# Docker out of Docker in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I launched my Jenkins agent insider a Docker container, using the image jenkins/inbound-agent as a base image and install the Docker CLI in it

https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/inbound-agent/

I launch the container like this:

```
docker run --detach \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /root/.ssh/:/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh \
--restart always \
--init jenkins/inbound-agent:4.9-1-jdk11 \
-url https://jenkins.url \
secret_key_for_jenkins_agent \
dood
```

I am able to launch some new containers inside the Jenkins agent container manually, no problem.

I can also specify stages like the one below to run some containers

```
    stage('Run in Docker') {
        steps {
            sh 'docker run alpine:latest ls'
        }
    }
```

But if I set the container as an agent like this

```
    stage('Run in Docker') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'alpine:latest'
                reuseNode true
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh "echo hello"
        }
    }
```

I then get the error

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -w /home/jenkins/workspace/Dockers -v /home/jenkins/workspace/Dockers:/home/jenkins/workspace/Dockers:rw,z -v /home/jenkins/workspace/Dockers@tmp:/home/jenkins/workspace/Dockers@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** alpine:latest cat
$ docker top 7a692e853148ab2ec522be205f493287ca58099fabfd9a3ebb890c29a82da1bf -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in home/jenkins/workspace/Dockers@tmp/durable-14231f71
(running Jenkins temporarily with -org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 7a692e853148ab2ec522be205f493287ca58099fabfd9a3ebb890c29a82da1bf
$ docker rm -f 7a692e853148ab2ec522be205f493287ca58099fabfd9a3ebb890c29a82da1bf
```

I suppose since the first version with just executing the shell command `docker run` works, then the docker CLI is installed correctly in the Jenkins agent container, right?

Entire Jenkins file

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'dood' }

    stages {
        // Pre build cleanup
        stage('Pre-build Clean Workspace') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }

        // Cloning Latest Patchset - Job is Gerrit Triggered
        stage('Clone Latest Patchset') {
            steps {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '$GERRIT_BRANCH']],
                    extensions: [
                        [
                            $class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                            disableSubmodules: false,
                            parentCredentials: true,
                            recursiveSubmodules: true,
                            reference: '',
                            trackingSubmodules: false
                            ],
                        [
                            $class: 'BuildChooserSetting',
                            buildChooser: [$class: 'GerritTriggerBuildChooser']
                            ],
                        [
                            $class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout',
                            deleteUntrackedNestedRepositories: true
                            ]
                    ],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [
                        [
                            credentialsId: 'xxxxxxx_SSH',
                            refspec: '$GERRIT_REFSPEC',
                            url: 'ssh://gerrit-ssh.xxxxxxxx.biz/xxxxxxxx/Dockers'
                            ]
                    ]
                ])
            }
        }

        stage('Run in Docker') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'alpine:latest'
                    reuseNode true
                    alwaysPull true
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh "echo hello"
            }
        }

        // Post build cleanup
        stage('Post-build Clean Workspace') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `docker: not found` indicates the `docker` CLI tool isn't installed in your image.  The linked question describes some approaches to address this in more detail.

Comment: Please show the entire Jenkinsfile.  I think you need to use option 'reuseNode',  `agent { docker {  image  'alping:latest'  reuseNode true } } `

Comment: @yong is correct. reuseNode seems to have gotten rid of the docker: not found message, which makes sense since I suppose without reuseNode, it will run on Jenkins Master. I will edit the original question with the new issue since it was closed as a duplicate

Comment: Please show your entire Jenkinsfile.

Comment: @yong Sorry I forgot. Do you see anything weird in the attached Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @Horace, I can run the pipeline only incudes `stage('Run in Docker')` on my Jenkins.  No wired thing in your Jenkinsfile.   You can give a try to remove other stages from pipeline, only retain `stage('Run in Docker')` and change `sh "echo hello"`  to `sh "ls"`,  to see what will happen with doing that.

Comment: @yong do you have any insights as to how you launched the main docker agent in your env (The one on top of my dockerfile which is labeled "dood") Perhaps that is the main difference. I will update my post with the launch script

Comment: You can change your pipeline to keep only one `stage('Run in Docker')`, if report same issue,  please open new post.   We can't add answer on this post due to it's marked "Duplicate"